# Now and Today properties with different date formats?

Tags: .net, vb.net

Do "Now" and "Today" have any dependency on system date and time format ?
I know they returns system Date/ Time but will my system date/time format make a difference ?

Consider 3 Aug 2015, will it always return same even though on my system local date format is dd/mm/yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy ?

Thanks for help.

Comment: It will always *mean* Aug 3, but it may show as "Aout" when the system is using the French culture settings (same for currency symbols and seperators).

Comment: thanks @Plutonix,
Can you please guide even if I have different culture (as well as different date time formats) it will be same ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Date` is just VB shorthand for the .NET Framework's `DateTime` structure.  The `DateTime` structure simply stores a single 64-bit integer value.  The meaning of that integer value is the total number of ticks after midnight on the first of January in the year 1 AD.  A *tick* is defined as 100 nanoseconds.  Therefore, it doesn't matter what culture you are in, the meaning of the value is always the same.  The only thing that changes about `DateTime` values is the way that they are represented when they are converted to strings.  When you convert a `DateTime` object to a string, it will, by default, use the rules of the current culture to determine the proper format.  However, you can force it to use a particular formatting, regardless of the current culture.  Here are a list of the [standard formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx), and here is how to define a [custom format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx).